# How to redirect the user to where they were before login (auth0 react)

Tags: reactjs, auth0

The scenario:

1. the user tries to access a secured page, they are not authenticated so
2. they are redirected to the login page (auth0)
3. once redirected, the user should be redirected to the page he tried to access before the authentication process began

After reading [the docs](https://auth0.com/docs/users/redirect-users-after-login?_ga=2.129634959.2039263595.1627045019-1269320265.1613559167&_gl=1*11ngo41*rollup_ga*MzM5MTgxMDY4LjE2MjI4MTU1NDc.*rollup_ga_F1G3E656YZ*MTYyNzA0NTAxOS41LjEuMTYyNzA1MTE5MC4zOA..), I am none the wiser. They suggest using [state parameters](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/state-parameters). For illustration purposes, I'll use the example on this [page](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/):

```
const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = ({ children }) => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;

  const history = useHistory();

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
    history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

The first thing I've tried is to modify the `redirectUri`, but then I'd have to specify all of them in the **Allowed Callback URLs**. I've then tried to go the cookies and browser sessions way but I have no idea at which point I have to set it and where.

In the `onRedirectCallback`, there's an `appState` parameter passed to it that apparently COULD contain a `returnTo` prop. But `appState` is always undefined... How/Where should I provide this?

Answer (score 3):

Forget about cookies and browser sessions. You also won't have to worry about creating a nonce as suggested [here](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/state-parameters). [You won't have to do this yourself](https://community.auth0.com/t/redirecting-users-with-state-parameters/39520/2). You are right in guessing that you have to use this `returnTo` prop. You have to provide it when calling `loginWithRedirect`:

```
loginWithRedirect({
    screen_hint,
    appState: {
       returnTo: window.location.pathname // here
    }
})
```

and `appState` won't be `undefined` anymore.

Note: by the time `onRedirectCallback` is called, `window.location.pathname` is equal to `'/'`. When you pass it through `loginWithRedirect`, it is equal to whatever path the user tried to access. It's NOT THE SAME.